# Conditionally make textboxfor required in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textboxfor and required checkbox. If user checked on the checkbox make textboxfor required and if not not checked allow null value in textboxfor. How to do this?

Here is my jquery code

```
 $("#AllowPhNumber").click(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#phone1").show();
            $("#phone").hide();
            }
            else {
            $("#phone").hide();
            $("#phone1").attr("disable", "disable");
            }
    });

  <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Allow Phone Number</label>


                @Html.CheckBox("AllowPhNumber", Model.AllowPhNumber.HasValue ? Model.AllowPhNumber : false)

            </div>

            <div id="phone" class="form-group" >
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="login_field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { type = "number", max = "999999999999", min = "0", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="phone1" class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="login_field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { type = "number", max = "999999999999", min = "0", required = "required", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code please share it

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Give the id phone and phone 1 to the text box code i.e `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { type = "number", max = "999999999999", min = "0", required = "required", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @id = 'phone'} })`  not to the div

Comment: and in conditions of your script write in this way `$('#phone').prop("required", true)` and for removing use this `$('#phone').removeAttr('required')`

Comment: my script is  $("#AllowPhNumber").click(function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             
       
                $("#phone").prop("required", true)
            }
            else {
                
                $("#phone").removeAttr("required")
            }
        });

Comment: but still not working. It is always remains required field

Comment: see by adding an alert before the if condition to check whether your function is getting called when your checkbox is clicked

Comment: i put the alert and you are right function is not called..What to do now

Comment: add id manually to your checkbox razor code `@Html.CheckBox("AllowPhNumber", Model.AllowPhNumber.HasValue ? Model.AllowPhNumber : false, new {@Id = 'AllowPhNumber'})` and then see if it's working or not.

Comment: Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` of similar conditional attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your Question you want that on check the fields are required and on uncheck they are not. In this case you can use this:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AllowPhNumber").on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $("#phone1").show();
                    $("#phone1").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "required");
                    $("#phone").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "required");
                    $("#phone").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#phone").show();
                    $("#phone").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "");
                    $("#phone1").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "");
                    $("#phone1").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

As per your HTML it shows that you are hiding one div on check so you have to make only the shown textbox required:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AllowPhNumber").on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $("#phone1").show();
                    $("#phone1").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "required");
                    $("#phone").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "");
                    $("#phone").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#phone").show();
                    $("#phone").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "required");
                    $("#phone1").find("input[type='number']").prop("required", "");
                    $("#phone1").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have a problem AllowPhNumber on click is not getting called

Comment: Change below line @Html.CheckBox("AllowPhNumber", Model.AllowPhNumber.HasValue ? Model.AllowPhNumber : false) to @Html.CheckBox("AllowPhNumber", Model.AllowPhNumber.HasValue ? Model.AllowPhNumber : false, new { @id="AllowPhNumber" })

Comment: Mady it is giving me an error "cannot convert from bool? to bool"

Comment: you have taken `AllowPhNumber` in model as `nullable` type. Use `bool` in place of `bool?` in the `model class`